# How to highlight a DataGrid row based on DateTime using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, wpf-style

My application contains a datagrid which is bound to an observable collection of objects from a single SQL database table.  Once of the columns contains a Date and Time and I would like to highlight the rows that are older than 30 minutes.

XAML

```
<!--DataGrid style-->
<Style x:Key="DataGridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value="{DynamicResource ColumnHeaderStyle}"/>
    <Setter Property="CellStyle"  Value="{DynamicResource DataGridCellStyle}"/>
</Style>
<!--DataGridColumnHeader style-->
<Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="25"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE5ECEF"/>
</Style>

<DataGrid x:Name="licenseGrid"
        ItemsSource="{Binding LoggedUsers}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLicenses}"
        Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle}"
        Grid.Row="5"
        Grid.Column="2"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="7"
        Height="525"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        HeadersVisibility="Column"
        SelectionMode="Extended"
        CanUserDeleteRows="True"
        EnableRowVirtualization="False">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsGhost}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFCBE8F6"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFCBE8F6"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button x:Name="revokeBtn"
                        ToolTip="Revoke Selected License or Licenses"
                        Content="Revoke"
                        Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.RevokeSelectedCommand}" 
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Computer" Binding="{Binding machineName}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE5ECEF"/>
                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="90"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Windows User" Binding="{Binding userName}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE5ECEF"/>
                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="95"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="MediaDent User" Binding="{Binding userId}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE5ECEF"/>
                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="90"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Session ID" Binding="{Binding tsSessionId}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE5ECEF"/>
                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="65"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Application" Binding="{Binding appId}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE5ECEF"/>
                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="65"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date In" Binding="{Binding dateIn}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE5ECEF"/>
                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="135"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Ping" Binding="{Binding lastPing}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE5ECEF"/>
                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="135"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Record ID" Binding="{Binding Id}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

As you can see, I've start with a `DataTrigger` in `DataGrid.RowStyle` but I am not sure if that's the best route to take. Any suggestions or references would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When reading the requirements:

> I would like to highlight the rows that are older than 30 minutes.

I would come to a different solution:

Bind the background of the row to the DateTime column and apply a ValueConverter that turns the the DateTime into a color(brush).